# Tomcat Virtual Host & Wildcard dns matching

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

I have created an application which needs to accept wildcard dns and request to database using that wildcard value. I tried to simulate a virtual environment for myself to achieve what I want like this:

1) in my Linux OS I changed the /etc/hosts and add these lines :

```
127.0.0.1   test-domain.com
127.0.0.1   mehdi.test-domain.com
```

2) I changed my tomcat server.xml file as follows :

```
<Host name="test-domain.com" 
    appBase="webapps/ROOT" 
    unpackWARs="true" 
    autoDeploy="true"
    xmlValidation="false" 
    xmlNamespaceAware="false">
    <Alias>www.test-domain.com</Alias>
    <Context path="" docBase="."/>
</Host>

<Host name="*.test-domain.com" 
        appBase="webapps/ROOT" 
        unpackWARs="true" 
        autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" 
        xmlNamespaceAware="false">
        <Alias>*.test-domain.com</Alias>
        <Context path="" docBase="."/>
</Host>
```

3) I deploy my project war file 'Root.war' into the ${TOMCAT}/webapps/ROOT folder

*now* when I request "*www.test-domain.com*" I see the web home page, and I want when I type this url "*mehdi.test-domain.com*", I fetch mehdi from the URL and do something with it and show mehdi page to my users.

**Question 1:** How I can fetch the wildcard value in my application ?

**Question 2:** Is it possible that we let tomcat convert the request URL to something else at runtime like this and pass it to the application (I need the wildcard value ex: mehdi)?

> http://mehdi.test-domain.com     CONVERT TO http://test-domain.com/mehdi

**Question 3:** Is it possible to have only the second *< Host name=...* definition and remove the first one? how could I handle it inside my application ?

Answer (score 1):

Q1: use request.getServerName()

Q2: you can use UrlRewrite filter or similar

Q3: AFAIK wildcards are not supported so you will need single Host name="localhost" that will receive all requests
See also [How to host random or wildcard subdomains on Tomcat and Java](http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/host-random-wildcard-subdomains-tomcat-java)